# Pass in file text into hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap, jfilechooser

I am having a bit of an issues trying to pass in a file read by my program and sorted accordantly. I am not used to working with files, and i ran out of ideas as to how this could be achieved.

/////////////////////////////////////// class reads file ///////////////////////////////////

import java.io.*;
public class InFileReader {

private BufferedReader inputStream = null;

private String fileLine;

private StringBuilder sb;

public String getFile(File fileRead) throws FileNotFoundException,
      IOException {

```
inputStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileRead)); //reads files
sb = new StringBuilder();
while((fileLine = inputStream.readLine()) != null){//keep reading lines in file till there is none
  sb.append(fileLine).append("\n");
}
return sb.toString(); //returns StringBuffer read values in String form
```

}
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////// end of read file class ///////////////////////

public void getFile(File fileRead) throws FileNotFoundException,
      IOException {

```
  try {

    String input = fileReader.getFile(fileRead.getAbsoluteFile());

    HashMap<Integer, Thing.Ship> hashmap = new HashMap<>();
    while (!input.isEmpty()) { // as long as there is data in the file keep looping 
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(input); // scan file

      if (!input.startsWith("//")) {   // take out "//"  from directory 
        String type = "";
        if (sc.hasNext()) {  // if there are character lines get next line
          type = sc.next();

        }
        if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("port")) { // looks for "port"
          world.assignPort(new Thing.SeaPort(sc)); // assigns value  to Seaport 
        } else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("dock")) {
          world.assignDock(new Thing.Dock(sc));
        } else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("ship")) {
          Thing.Ship s = new Thing.Ship(sc);
          hashmap.put(s.getIndex(), s);
          world.assignShip(s);
        } else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("pship")) {
          Thing.Ship s = new Thing.PassengerShip(sc);
          hashmap.put(s.getIndex(), s);
          world.assignShip(s);
        } else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("cship")) {
          Thing.Ship s = new Thing.CargoShip(sc);
          hashmap.put(s.getIndex(), s);
          world.assignShip(s);
        } else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("person")) {
          world.assignPerson(new Thing.Person(sc));
        }
      }
    }
    //inputOut.setText(type);
    inputOut.setText(world.toString());
  } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e + "-----");
  }
```

}

Here fileRead knows where to find the file to be read "C:\Users\abe\IdeaProjects\CreateSeaPortDataFile\src\text.txt"

public void getFile(File fileRead) throws FileNotFoundException,
      IOException {

this is where things just fall apart:

String input = fileReader.getFile(fileRead.getAbsoluteFile());

My intent here is to pass the location of the file so that the getFile class can read it and then be sorted into the hashmap. 
again i am not familiar with how to work with file, any suggestion or comment would be greatly appreciated.
thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

If you get a FileNotFoundException then the file was not found.
You say the filename was "C:\Users\abe\IdeaProjects\CreateSeaPortDataFile\src\text.txt". 
If you type that name in the code you must escape the backslash:

```
"C:\\Users\\abe\\IdeaProjects\\CreateSeaPortDataFile\\src\\text.txt".
```

Comment: so the main issue is here 

String input = fileReader.getFile(fileRead.getAbsoluteFile());

fileRead.getAbsoluteFile() <--- equal "C:\\Users\\abe\\IdeaProjects\\CreateSeaPortDataFile\\src\\text.txt". 

but  fileReader.getFile(fileRead.getAbsoluteFile()); <-- is null

the value is not being assigned

Comment: is  String input = fileReader.getFile(fileRead.getAbsoluteFile());   null due to the FileNotFoundException thrown?

Comment: You don't show the code where fileRead is assigned. You could try this:
    File fileRead = new File(C:\\Users\\abe\\IdeaProjects\\CreateSeaPortDataFile\\src\\t‌​ext.txt");
Does the is error still there?

Comment: public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
if (e.getSource() == loadFile) { fileInField = new JFileChooser();
      fileInField.setCurrentDirectory(new File("."));
      if (fileInField.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        try { if(fileInField!=null) { //checks for file
            getFile(fileInField.getSelectedFile()); //sets directory for file to be access
            txtEntry();}
        } catch (IOException e1) {e1.printStackTrace(); }
        } else {  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: You didn't choose a file.", "Error", 1);}}

Comment: The code above is so that when i click a jButton it loads the txt file to be read

Comment: the  class reads file " public String getFile(File fileRead) " class goes through each line and should assign those values here
String input = fileReader.getFile(fileRead.getAbsoluteFile());

Comment: i have debugged the code, and everything falls apart here
String input = fileReader.getFile(fileRead.getAbsoluteFile());  
which is my 
"public String getFile(File fileRead) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {"

Comment: I can't figure out how to read every line of the txt file and pass those values to my hashmap to be sorted

Comment: I copied your code and tested it.
You should change the start of the getFile(...) to:
   String input = fileReader.getFile(fileRead.getAbsoluteFile());
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(input); // scan file

   HashMap<Integer, Thing.Ship> hashmap = new HashMap<>();
   while (sc.hasNext()) { // as long as there is data in the file keep looping
    String type = sc.next();

    if (!type.startsWith("//")) { // take out "//" from directory